# Apache X509 certificate auth mode setting HTTP headers

Tags: apache, http, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

How can we set X509 certificate parameters in HTTP header from Apache?

my web proxy configuration contains

```
RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s"
```

above will set complete certificate into HTTP header. I will get it from HTTP header in my servlet.

But I need to set [individual parameter](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/ssl/ssl_compat.html) like

```
SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN
SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_OU
```

I have set like this,

```
RequestHeader set SSL_SERVER_S_DN_O "%{SSL_SERVER_S_DN_O}s"
RequestHeader set SSL_SERVER_I_DN_OU "%{SSL_SERVER_I_DN_OU}s"
```

But its not working!

Is there any parser/modules available for do this in Apache? 
Please help me on this.

Comment: Have you set `SSLOptions StdEnvVars` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry folks, Forgot to load module.

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

After adding this I can set and retrieve all available parameter in certificate.